# Wordpress timeouts at 30 seconds

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, timeout

I have a wordress blog and there is plugin that does around 20000 SQL inserts on user request. I noticed that the process takes long time, which is normal, but the request times out at 30 seconds.
I checked PHP settings and notice that PHP max_execution_time was 30 second, so I increased it to 90, but the requst keeps to timeout at 30 seconds (I even logged what does ini_get('max_execution_time') return and it says "30". Then, I checked if there are any apache directives that limit request time and found that there is a "TimeOut" directive ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout )
Its value was 60 and I increased it to 90 as well, but the problem persist - the request times out after 30 seconds as it was before I changed anything.

as a note: I restart the server after I do any modification

Comment: How did you changed `max_execution_time`, with `ini_set`? If so if PHP run in safe mode it'll not work.

Comment: no, it was changed from php.ini file

Comment: Look into phpinfo to see which ini file is used.

Answer (score 0):

**By modifying your PHP Settings**
That’s not easy, as you need to have access to your server, or a way to change your PHP settings. If you have access to your php.ini, you need to look for the max_execution_time variable and set it to the number of seconds you would like, 60 seconds for example.

max_execution_time = 60

If that doesn’t work, or can’t access your php.ini, you can also try to set this variable by using the .htaccess (at the root of your WordPress install). You can add this line.

php_value max_execution_time 60

If you set the value to 0 (instead of 60, here), the process will be allowed to run forever. Don’t do this, you will run into much bigger issues, extremely difficult to resolve.

**By calling a function in PHP**
This is generally not really recommended to do this. But if you know what you are doing, you can tell PHP that you would like the process to run for more time. For this, you could write this call in your theme, in the functions.php for example.

set_time_limit(100);